# SSE 64 bit registers

Tags: c++, sse

I was wondering, can I sum, or multiply, two float32 variables?

Is it worth doing all sums and multiplications that happens very much (e.g. in videogames while calculating simple bullet trajectories) in SSE registers?

Comment: No.  It is worth learning how to use a profiler.

Comment: @HansPassant why are you writing about profiler? I just want to enhance some mathematical functions.

Comment: Because compilers already use SSE instructions for floating point and you have absolutely no idea if there's any point in trying to do a better job than the compiler did.  You could be making it *slower* and still not notice any difference.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks so much for been so clear. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of SSE is indeed to process a lot of numbers quickly. And the ability to process two numbers at a time helps a lot with that. For instance, you can indeed add a step `{dx, dy}` to a coordinate `{x, y}` in a single instruction (`ADDPS`). It could in fact add 4 floats, since the registers are 128 bits, but that might be unnecessary for your case. `ADDPD` splits the 128 bits in 2x64 so it adds two doubles. ("float64")

Comment: Note however that most modern x86 CPUs have two FPUs, so there's not much to be gained from 2-wide SIMD operations. If you can do 4 floats at a time though then that should be a 2x win over scalar code.

Comment: @PaulR: Might want to check your documentation again. There's a tiny speck of truth in that AMD Bulldozer shares its FPU's between cores, so a quad-core indeed has two FPU's. However, since they're SSE, even those can still process 4 floats at a time - so 8 in total.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with AMD CPUs, but current and recent Intel Core i7s have two FPUs per core, so you can issue two scalar floating point instructions per clock cycle.

Comment: @PaulR Depends on which instructions they are. `addss` has a throughput of 1/cycle (on Haswell, and it was never better), so no luck there (well, you can do a multiplication at the same time). `mulss` and FMA instructions have a throughput of 2/cycle on Haswell, 1 on earlier µarchs. Strange how you can two additions in a cycle but only if you throw in a no-op multiplication by 1.0..

Comment: @PaulR: Right, now I understand what you meant. These units are usually not called "FPU's" but Execution Units, and the two EU's share a single stack of FPU registers. And as harold points out, the fastest x86 designs have 2 SSE EU's per core as well.

Comment: All points noted - I should have been more precise and said FP execution units of course - the best excuse I can come up with just now is jet lag. ;-)